# Project A can't reference a class in Project B

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So in my solution I've got two projects. `A` and `B`.

In project `A` (My views project), I've added an assembly reference pointing to `B`(My `ViewModels` Project.)

So in code behind, finding a class in Project `B` works just fine.

```
using ViewModels.Appearance.Themes
```

The issue comes when I try to find it in XAML;

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewModels.Appearance.Themes;assembly=ViewModels">
```

Intellisense seems to detect it as a valid location, but when I try and use the class in that namespace...

```
<Rectangle x:Key="WindowBackgroundContent" x:Shared="false" >
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush local:BingImage.UseBingImage="True" Opacity=".3" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Intellisense tells me:

> The attachable property 'UseBingImage' was not found in type
>   'BingImage'.

It seems the only way to make it work is if the `BingImage.cs` class has a namespace that's directly in Project `B`'s root. But I'm not entirely comfortable braking the standard convention here.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a reference in your XAML, try to **Rebuild** your project once to recompile everything and to incorporate the referenced project and to make any new controls available. It is necessary when a file or a dependency  has been changed, or even with no reason. But it will solve your issue.