# Why is Visual Studio ignoring the new code I wrote?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a genetic algorithm program written in C# using Visual Studio. It worked fine at first, but now I opened the solution to edit and the code that I wrote doesn't work and VS ignores it, even the code block has an exception code.

Also when I add a button to the UI in design mode, it also doesn't show up at runtime. I can't understand why this happens. So the application is working as the last version. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try to *Clean* and *Rebuild* your project once. Read this answer to know more about *Rebuild* : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36655884/2946329

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on your solution in solution explorer and select clean, then rebuild and run solution