# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'int' When changing location of a label

Tags: c#, location, label, implicit-conversion

Trying my hand at making a simple moving avatar for a game, seems that I have a bit of trouble when trying to assign the character's new location.

```
private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Step = 2;
        label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X, label1.Location.Y + Step);
    }
```

I get the error above when I try to run.

Comment: This code should works fine. Have you tried to [Rebuild](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36655884) your project?

Comment: Change  `label1.Location.X` to `label1.X` etc.. or use `label1.Y += step;` directly

Comment: What are the definiton (typ) of Location?  What kind of environment for game development is that?