# I can't see my changes in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am working on windows form app in C#. 1 week ago I created a form and I add some tools. Today I opened same application. Now, I add new button but when I run it I can't see. Previous version of the application is shown. For example, there was a DataGridView and I changed it with listView but when I run the program I still see the DataGridView. Why this is happening?

Comment: Try to rebuild your project once. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36655884/2946329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild your project. **Build - RebuildProjectName**

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuild your project (Build->Rebuild Solution) before launch application. Maybe you have an error in your project and select option to start previous successful build.