# MVC ViewModel - Multiple models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

New to MVC and wanting to pass two models to the view. The idea being one is a list of data, the other is simply a `datetime` to show when it was last uploaded in bulk.

My models are:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public int IDX { get; set; }
    public string PyR { get; set; }
    public string CN { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B_R { get; set; }
    public DateTime L_I { get; set; }
}

public class DataUpdated
{
    public DateTime LastImport { get; set; }
}
```

And my view model is:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Model.DataModel> Data { get; set; }
    public Model.DataUpdated LastUploadDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am sending the view model to the view in the controller with:

```
ViewModels.DataViewModel vm = new ViewModels.DataViewModel();
vm.Data = C_List;
vm.LastUploadDate = du;
return View(vm);
```

I have then tried to reference this in my view, with:

```
@model CCA_Data.ViewModels.DataViewModel
```

But when I try and access the Data model from the view model in the following line of code in my view:

```
 @foreach (var Data in Model.Data)
```

I get the error:

> IENumerable < DataViewModel > does not contain a definition for
>   Data

2 questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Why does it think `DataViewModel` is `IENumerable`?

Comment: how do you send this ViewModel from the controller to the View?

Comment: how do you pass the model from your `Controller` to the `View` ?

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<CCA_Data.ViewModels.DataViewModel>`

Comment: @DrewKennedy The OP wants an `IEnumerable<Model.DataModel>` that is a member of `DataViewModel` class already. Why he should use `IEnumerable<CCA_Data.ViewModels.DataViewModel>`?

Comment: Updated the question with how I am passing the view model to the view in the controller.

Comment: But in there, I am specifying a model that is, and one that is not, so why, when not specified, does it take the viewmodel to be one? And not accept the reference to the model within that, that is?

Comment: Your variable names are terrible.  You should get into the habit of giving them meaningful names.

Comment: @Leonidas199x Have you tried to *rebuild* your project / *Restart* your visual studio? Your code seems to works fine.

Comment: change here : ViewModels.DataViewModel vm = new ViewModels.DataViewModel(); vm.Data =new Data();
            vm.Data = C_List;
            vm.LastUploadDate = du; and also check you are getting data in vm or not debug it.

Comment: @DarrenYoung my variables are not called that. I changed them due to sensitivity. I should have named them a little nicer for the example, I accept that.

Comment: Initialise the classes within `DataViewModel` after initialising the `DataViewModel` class before assigning values to them

Comment: @S.Akbari - That is all that was needed - Thank you. A stupid error on my part not to have tried that beforehand - Clean and rebuild.

Comment: @Leonidas199x It is necessary sometimes even with no reason. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36655884/2946329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering here so that others don't have to go through *all* of the comments...

Don't forget to Rebuild the project so that it can figure out all the namespaces and references.