# wpf error opening another form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I try to instantiate a new form through a button I get the error:

> 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'NewWindow' and
>   no extension method 'NewWindow' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

My forms are **MainWindow** and **NewWindow** and I have a button in the MainWindow which should open the NewWindow.

See below:

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Main Window"
    Height="400"
    Width="640"
>
<Grid>
    <Button
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Content="Open New Window"
            Width="200"
            Click="OpenNewWindow"
            Margin="0,10,10,0"
            x:Name="btOpenNewWindow"
        />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenNewWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            NewWindow nw = new NewWindow();
            nw.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**NewWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.NewWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="New Window"
    Height="400"
    Width="640"
    >
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="43,3,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

NewWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class NewWindow : Window
    {
        public NewWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Which line in which file throws the error?

Comment: this line -> NewWindow nw = new NewWindow(); in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: Try to clean your solution, or manually delete `obj` and `bin` folders. Looks like a compilation issue.

Comment: Well that constructor does not match your error. Perhaps do try to clean and delete folders like @KostyaK says. And also try restarting VS if that doesn't work.

Comment: try to *Rebuild* your project once to recompile everything. Reason:https://stackoverflow.com/a/36655884/2946329

Comment: I tried that, still the error persists

Comment: I took your code.... working for me without any issues....expect you do not have </window> close tag.

Comment: The worst thing is that it makes no sense, I feel tied

Comment: Try restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: @jairhumberto try restarting Visual Studio or better yet rebooting your box.

Comment: yes I have the window close tag. It was cutted from my copy-paste :/

Comment: Also ensure, you did not mess up with namespace anywhere

Comment: @katamarayudu  there'd be a different error in this case

Comment: I restart visual studio, but the error persists. I'll try to create a new project

Comment: I did create a new project and it worked, so who knows what happened