# Application Runs Fine, But Form Design Appears Blank

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to make it so that my form does not appear blank. It was working before, It wouldn't let me save my file at one point so I renamed it to **form3temp** and now the form shows up when I run it, but not when I look at it in design view. Form 5 also does the same thing. The rest of my 7 forms are fine.

How it appears inside design
https://i.gyazo.com/06994988ff2f307d5042c0bafec1c43e.png
How it appears when I run the application
https://gyazo.com/97c1838e55f5f595b09211f2ee742c9f

```
namespace LawnCarePrototype
{
    public partial class Form31 : Form
    {
        public static decimal yardCost = 0.0M;
        decimal yardSizeMultiplier = 0.0M;

        public Form31()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            yardSizeMultiplier = 0.0M;
            yardCost = 0.0M;

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                yardSizeMultiplier = 0.8M;
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                yardSizeMultiplier = 1.0M;
            }
            if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                yardSizeMultiplier = 1.2M;
            }

            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                yardCost =+ 15.00M * yardSizeMultiplier;
                //2 EDGE
                Global.edgeExp = 15.00M * yardSizeMultiplier;
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                yardCost =+30.00M * yardSizeMultiplier;
                Global.bushExp = 30.00M * yardSizeMultiplier;

                //3 BUSH
            }
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                yardCost =+ 25.00M * yardSizeMultiplier;
                Global.leafExp = 25.00M * yardSizeMultiplier;
                //4 LEAF
            }
            if (checkBox4.Checked)
            {
                yardCost =+ 35.00M * yardSizeMultiplier;
                //1 LAWN
                Global.MowExp = 35.00M * yardSizeMultiplier;
            }
            if (yardCost == 0.00M)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Input Your Selection");
            }
            else
            {
                Form4 form4obj = new Form4();
                form4obj.Show();
                this.Close();

            }

            Global.subTotal = yardCost;
        }


        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2obj = new Form2();
            form2obj.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I expect the form design to appear because I don't see any errors.

Not sure what could be causing this in my code.

Side Note: Sorry for the poor code format!

Comment: Try to *Rebuild* your solution once. Reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/36655884/2946329

Comment: change `form2obj.Show();` to `form2obj.ShowDialog();`