# C# Form1 not showing

Tags: c#, winforms

When i Start my winForms program it boots up, but my Form1 does NOT show.

i have tried to write `Console.WriteLine("Here");` in Form1_load but that doesnt get logged. I have also tried the Logging command after `InitializeComponent();` - Like so

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Console.WriteLine("Here");

    }
```

But that doesn't get logged either. So it can't just be the Form hiding.

Here is the code in my Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form1.NativeMethods.AllocConsole();
        Console.WriteLine("Debug Console");
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        Form1.NativeMethods.FreeConsole();

    }
}
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Could you paste code from your `Program.cs`

Comment: Also try to rebuild your project once, it is necessary sometimes https://stackoverflow.com/a/36655884/2946329

Comment: added program.cs code

Comment: Does the application crash?

Comment: @TheGeneral No.

Comment: Does the "Debug Console" text appear in the console?

Comment: What is NativeMethods? Where is defined and what is this AllocConsole static method

Comment: @S.Akbari Rebuilding did not work

Comment: @HandbagCrab Yes it does.

Comment: I'm not sure the consequences of starting a console. however maybe you can just show the form  `(new Form1()).Show()`  in a standard way and use wait or reset event to stop the app from existing

Comment: What happens if you remove these allocConsole lines?

Comment: For anyone interested it appears to be [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/68979/Attaching-a-Console-to-a-WinForms-application).

Comment: I hate to put a downer on this, but this question was very poor, i mean, you left out what you were actually doing, just complained the form didn't show, Didn't show the uncommon code you were running, Haven't explained if you removed the code if this works or not. and haven't shown you have used the debugger. please think about these types of things in the future

Comment: If you comment out Form1.NativeMethods.AllocConsole() and Form1.NativeMethods.FreeConsole(); i belive your Form1 window will show

Comment: the thing is, that it worked like 30 mins ago, but now it doesn't and i havent changed anything with the form or the program.cs

Comment: @S.Akbari Yes.. It worked 30 mins ago

Comment: Form2 can show, Form1 cannot..?