# I cannot get the Data out of my MySql Database into my DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I do not get any error messages, but the Datagrid won't show any Data from my Database.

```
var con = new MySqlConnection("server= localhost; database=fußballmanager; Uid=root;Pwd=;");

private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_anmeldedaten", con);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
 }
```

Comment: I can't  see any problem with your code. Are you sure your `Form4_Load` is executed? Put a break-point inside it to make sure it is executed. Also try to rebuild your project again.

Comment: You are right, for any reason `Form4_Load` isn't executed. But I don't know why ?

Comment: Okay after I rebuilded the code, it works. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is necessary sometimes. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36655884/2946329